# Why does Solrj SolrDocumentList (SolrDocument) hold data items as Arrays (ArrayList<>)

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using `Solrj 6.2.0` to access a local `Solr` core.

Everything works fine. I can search and find all the data I require.

I have one issue in that the `QueryResponse` `getResults()` method returns a `SolrDocumentList`, which is a collection of `SolrDocument`.

Each of the `SolrDocument` hold a single data item as an array, when I retrieve each data item I receive an `ArrayList`.

I have to loop through the `ArrayList`s single entry and return a String.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any way to get `SolrJ` to return `SolrDocument` that holds a data item as a Non Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure the field is a single value (or you need just the first value of the collection), you can use the [getFirstValue(String name)](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=lucene-solr.git;a=blob;f=solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.java;h=b4af06f903b1a8656530062f7339b95fea06c848;hb=764d0f19151dbff6f5fcd9fc4b2682cf934590c5#l176) method of the `SolrDocument`.

Comment: Thanks, it works a treat, I do not know how I missed that method

Comment: And the _reason_ why it is this way, is because the fields in the default, managed schema / schemaless mode are multivalued by default, meaning that they'll be returned as a list.